# Opening spatial weights matrix file (SWM) from ArcGIS for Desktop in Excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, table

I successfully generate spatial weights matrix file (SWM) to get the nearest neighbors for polygons shapes in ArcMap 10.2.2 but I am confused how to open this file its a compressed file and when I try t open it I get error to open the compressed file.

I searched on net and found that this file can be converted to table and open in excel but I didn't find the tool that can do this in the ArcMap any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is created in **binary** file format so the values in the file **cannot be viewed directly**. To view or edit the feature relationships in an SWM file, use the [Convert_Spatial_Weights_Matrix_to_Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/005p/005p0000003t000000.htm) tool.

This tool will convert a binary spatial weights matrix file (.swm) to a table (that you can then export to Excel with the GP tool [Table to Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_To_Excel/001200000054000000/).

Comment: thanks alex for replying but I confused on how to access this tool through arc map 10.2.2 I followed this path Desktop » Geoprocessing » Tool reference » Spatial Statistics toolbox but from the page that you post it above but I couldn't find it there

Comment: You should access this tool from ArcToolbox - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003q0000001m000000